# Mysql Update SET data type values

Tags: mysql

I have SET data type field in Mysql table, which contains values SET('dog','cat','hamster'). I would like to update value 'dog' into 'puppy' and as well change values in all records from 'dog' into 'puppy'. Thank you.

Comment: Please read the MySQL documentation or any of the 100s of online tutorials first before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these three query's:

```
ALTER TABLE `table `CHANGE `field` `field` SET ('dog','cat','hamster', 'puppy' );
update table `table` set `field` ='puppy' where `field`='dog';

ALTER TABLE `table `CHANGE `field` `field` SET ('cat','hamster', 'puppy' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Jens will work only when `field` has values 'dog' and nothing else. But this one is `SET` and not `ENUM`. Thus it can have `field` with multiple values which also includes 'dog'. For example - 'dog,cat', 'dog,hamster', 'dog,cat,hamster'. In such cases this answer won't work. Also here `CHANGE` is unnecessary and `MODIFY` will suffice. I have provided the code below which will work in any scenario -

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    -> id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> animal SET("dog","cat","hamster"),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );

INSERT INTO my_table (animal) VALUES ("dog");
INSERT INTO my_table (animal) VALUES ("dog,cat");
INSERT INTO my_table (animal) VALUES ("dog,hamster");
INSERT INTO my_table (animal) VALUES ("dog,cat,hamster");

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----------------+
| id | animal          |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | dog             |
|  2 | dog,cat         |
|  3 | dog,hamster     |
|  4 | dog,cat,hamster |
+----+-----------------+

ALTER TABLE my_table
    -> MODIFY animal SET (
    -> "dog","cat","hamster","puppy");

DESCRIBE my_table;
+--------+------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int unsigned                       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| animal | set('dog','cat','hamster','puppy') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

UPDATE my_table
    -> set animal = CASE
    -> WHEN animal LIKE "dog"
    -> THEN REPLACE(animal,"dog","puppy")
    -> WHEN animal LIKE "dog%"
    -> THEN REPLACE(animal,"dog,","puppy,")
    -> WHEN animal LIKE "%dog%"
    -> THEN REPLACE(animal,",dog",",puppy")
    -> ELSE animal
    -> END;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------------------+
| id | animal            |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | puppy             |
|  2 | cat,puppy         |
|  3 | hamster,puppy     |
|  4 | cat,hamster,puppy |
+----+-------------------+

ALTER TABLE my_table
    -> MODIFY animal SET("cat","hamster","puppy");

DESCRIBE my_table;
+--------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int unsigned                 | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| animal | set('cat','hamster','puppy') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The original credit goes to @Jens though.